# strange behavior of branch remote HEAD

Tags: git

Sometimes I'm getting message that some branch is ahead of origin by # commits. Actually, I did not create those commits and they are pulled from origin.

```
$> git pull origin develop
Enter passphrase for key '###': 
remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From ssh://git.#############
 * branch            develop    -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating bbe5577..71907bc
Fast-forward
 ############### |    1 -
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

And

```
$> git st
# On branch develop
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit.
```

`tig`'s output:

```
{date} {author} [develop] {message1}
{date} {author} [origin/develop] {message2}
```

So, if I'm understanding all right, origin's HEAD is my local HEAD (or something like that) backed by 1. But nobody fix that origin's HEAD to `-1` state.

Why did it happened?

Then I push to that branch and get "everything up-to date"

```
$> git push origin develop
Enter passphrase for key '###': 
Everything up-to-date
```

Can someone explain what's going on with that branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is to use `git fetch origin` followed by `git merge origin/develop` from your local develop branch

`git pull` is like a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge` on your local branch develop.  origin/develop in your current repository won't match your local develop branch though because your local copy is one commit ahead from your origin/develop HEAD.  The call to `git push origin develop` updates your local origin/develop when git realizes the change is already on the remote git repo.

Here's what you see locally on your machine with no changes:

```
macbook:test joel$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
macbook:test joel$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
macbook:test joel$
```

On another machine another user makes a change, commits it, and pushes it to origin/master:

```
otherPerson-pc:test bob$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
otherPerson-pc:test bob$ echo "ddd" >> newfile.txt 
otherPerson-pc:test bob$ git add newfile.txt 
otherPerson-pc:test bob$ git commit --message "added to newfile in master remotely"
[master d14b77e] added to newfile in master remotely
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
otherPerson-pc:test bob$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 314 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To /Users/joel/Desktop/test/test.git
   2cfa7d4..d14b77e  master -> master
otherPerson-pc:test bob$
```

Back on my local copy I haven't made a change.  I pull from origin master to get changes from others and appear one commit ahead!:

```
macbook:test joel$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
macbook:test joel$ git pull origin master
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From /Users/joel/Desktop/test/test
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 2cfa7d4..d14b77e
Fast-forward
 newfile.txt |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

macbook:test joel$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
macbook:test joel$
```

My local master has changes applied from the remote's master but my copy of origin/master is 1 commit behind so git says I'm one commit ahead locally even though I'm up to date.  The `git push origin master` updates origin/master locally and the message goes away.

You can avoid this by using `git fetch` and `git merge` instead of `git pull`

The other developer might do this again:

```
otherPerson-pc:test bob$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
otherPerson-pc:test bob$ echo "gggg" >> newfile.txt 
otherPerson-pc:test bob$ git add newfile.txt 
otherPerson-pc:test bob$ git commit --message "added gggg newfile in master remotely"
[master 677d031] added eeee newfile in master remotely
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
otherPerson-pc:test bob$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 321 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
To /Users/joel/Desktop/test/test.git
   d14b77e..677d031  master -> master
otherPerson-pc:test bob$
```

Locally I'll git fetch all of origin and then manually merge origin/master to my copy of merge.

```
macbook:test joel$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)


macbook:test joel$ git fetch origin 
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From /Users/joel/Desktop/test/test
   5e335fa..2dae61c  master     -> origin/master

macbook:test joel$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

macbook:test joel$ git merge origin/master
Updating 5e335fa..2dae61c
Fast-forward
 newfile.txt |    1 +
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)

macbook:test joel$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
macbook:test joel$
```

I usually do a fetch and then merge because you can check for conflicts before you you merge using git diff.